# Are street numbers in addresses in geographic order in Taiwan?

Tags: factoids, taiwan

Are street numbers in Taiwan addresses in geographic order, like in Australia and the USA, or are they in chronological order, as often happens in Japan?

Comment: I don't know about Taiwan, but it might be beneficial to mention which city. I know in Mexico, this varies greatly by city (or even neighborhood or street).

Comment: Perhaps zooming in on google maps might show how the street numbers are arranged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They're in geographic order.**   However, long Taiwanese roads are broken up into "sections" (段), each of which restarts the numbering.  So if you look at these two addresses:

```
#456, Xinyi Rd Sec. 4, Xinyi District, Taipei City
#16, Xinyi Rd Sec. 5, Xinyi District, Taipei City
```

"#16" (Sec. 5) is actually further away from the city center than "#456" (Sec. 4).

In practice, though, most street numbers (號) are in relation to alleys (弄) and lanes (巷), not the main road.  Put it all together and you get something like this:

```
12 F, #88, Alley 10, Lane 78, Xinyi Road Sec. 4, Xinyi District, Taipei City 10204
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_addresses_in_Taiwan) goes into a bit more detail.